# How to retrieve a YouTube video's tags with YouTube v3 API?

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-api

I want to retrieve the tags for a specific YouTube video using v3 of the YouTube API.

I'm able to retrieve a video with this request to the search endpoint, https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=cats&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}.

Now I hit the video endpoint trying to get the tags for the video from the above query.
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=IytNBm8WA1c&part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Response,

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"PMn2rAVTRiZHkX45qiqfcLZoTXM/rYBuk4KeZFmSMoiSuaXfy6-Pm28\"",
 "items": [
  {

   "id": "IytNBm8WA1c",
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"PMn2rAVTRiZHkX45qiqfcLZoTXM/_6K6Qz8rLYf0d5gUnucV1LwbwU4\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2007-07-09T14:02:03.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCFMV3DqmnaRc4oNGvi-3OvQ",
    "title": "Funny Cats",
    "description": "it's soo funny :D\r\n\r\naudio content is licensed by UMG\r\n\r\nSong 1: Gioachino Rossini - The Thieving Magpie  0:00 - 1:37\r\nSong 2: The Presidents of the United States of America - Kitty  1:38 - 2:47\r\nSong 3: The Nutcracker  2:48 - 3:51\r\nSong 4: Smash Mouth - All Star  3:51 - 7:06\r\nSong 5: The Wiseguys - Ooh La La  7:07 - 7:43\r\n\r\nPS: i will ignore messages with the subject\r\n\"Business Proposal Regarding Your YouTube Videos\"",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IytNBm8WA1c/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IytNBm8WA1c/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IytNBm8WA1c/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "nguoap",
    "categoryId": "15"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

API Explorer for this request - https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?id=IytNBm8WA1c&part=snippet&_h=3&

Even if I authorize this request I get the same results. Although, **if the account being authorized owns the video it returns the tags**.

How can I get the tags for the videos I own without asking the end-user to authorize their accounts? This implementation is client side with JS.

UPDATE: GData Issue Link: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4513

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list it appears that the latest version of the YouTube API now returns tags:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key={API-key}&fields=items(snippet(title,description,tags))&part=snippet&id={video_id}
```

Comment: Better late than never! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at present you can only get videos with tags when you authenticate yourself as the owner of the channel. Searching for tags used to work, but [is broken](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4247) in the current V2 implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Following method to fetch YouTube title, description and tags

1. First of all create Google API key 
   https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard
2. go to credentials - create API key
   https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?folder=&organizationId=&project=
3. enable YouTube API
   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=
4. download postman software to POST data on google server YouTube API
   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=your-key&fields=items(snippet(title,description,tags))&part=snippet&id=youtube-id