# YouTube API v3 Hashtag Search bad results

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to get the same results when I do a basic hashtag search on YouTube, like so:

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%23beautyblogger

via the API but my results are way off, oftentimes returning videos that don't include the search term at all.

Here's the request I'm making:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=MY-API-KEY&part=snippet&q=%23beautyblogger

And the results:

```
{
  kind:"youtube#searchListResponse",
  etag:""  kiOs9cZLH2FUp6r6KJ8eyq_LIOk/i5Di8j0849qCyu2Tmld5tGkydbI"",
  nextPageToken:"CAMQAA",
  regionCode:"US",
  pageInfo:{
    totalResults:562,
    resultsPerPage:3
  },
  items:[
    {
      kind:"youtube#searchResult",
      etag:""      kiOs9cZLH2FUp6r6KJ8eyq_LIOk/vn2S6wZ0OslYJuMhhbhtIlqU1IU"",
      id:{
        kind:"youtube#video",
        videoId:"9-JNIsGngVQ"
      },
      snippet:{
        publishedAt:"2014-08-21T11:32:49.000Z",
        channelId:"UCXeW7-Cm1Sj4yiH5GTNOonQ",
        title:"Ice Bucket Challange TH #BeautyBlogger #Als",
        description:"Video created with the Socialcam app: https://socialcam.com.",
        thumbnails:{
          default:{
            url:"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9-JNIsGngVQ/default.jpg",
            width:120,
            height:90
          },
          medium:{
            url:"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9-JNIsGngVQ/mqdefault.jpg",
            width:320,
            height:180
          },
          high:{
            url:"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9-JNIsGngVQ/hqdefault.jpg",
            width:480,
            height:360
          }
        },
        channelTitle:"beauty4ties",
        liveBroadcastContent:"none"
      }
    },
    {
      kind:"youtube#searchResult",
      etag:""      kiOs9cZLH2FUp6r6KJ8eyq_LIOk/pIFcPza36XlfcFxov8SKHlr8b84"",
      id:{
        kind:"youtube#video",
        videoId:"eJEZx3N_cM0"
      },
      snippet:{
        publishedAt:"2015-04-14T21:39:47.000Z",
        channelId:"UCwM3ZfCiQuq-65OGMKYuZ6Q",
        title:"Confessions of a Beauty Blogger",
        description:"A fun Q&A tag on Confessions of a Beauty Blogger...",
        thumbnails:{
          default:{
            url:"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eJEZx3N_cM0/default.jpg",
            width:120,
            height:90
          },
          medium:{
            url:"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eJEZx3N_cM0/mqdefault.jpg",
            width:320,
            height:180
          },
          high:{
            url:"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eJEZx3N_cM0/hqdefault.jpg",
            width:480,
            height:360
          }
        },
        channelTitle:"Karen Heidi Rees",
        liveBroadcastContent:"none"
      }
    },
    {
      kind:"youtube#searchResult",
      etag:""      kiOs9cZLH2FUp6r6KJ8eyq_LIOk/oz9Nm1GJb6xtqYeWq_3znkaYCWE"",
      id:{
        kind:"youtube#channel",
        channelId:"UC4PsH3qz3AYe6QJubmD45wQ"
      },
      snippet:{
        publishedAt:"2014-03-25T01:03:10.000Z",
        channelId:"UC4PsH3qz3AYe6QJubmD45wQ",
        title:"Synergy By Design #BeautyBlogger",
        description:"BeautyBlogger 》#Beauty ¤ #Makeup ¤ #Style 》BBA:MKT/PR ¤ #SocialMedia Expert 》Ranked Top#1% #SocialMediaInfluencer (Self-Taught)》100% Sicilian ...",
        thumbnails:{
          default:{
            url:"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-gUShxLkVxac/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/YzSK2QBuysw/s88-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
          },
          medium:{
            url:"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-gUShxLkVxac/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/YzSK2QBuysw/s240-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
          },
          high:{
            url:"https://yt3.ggpht.com/-gUShxLkVxac/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/YzSK2QBuysw/s240-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
          }
        },
        channelTitle:"Synergy By Design #BeautyBlogger",
        liveBroadcastContent:"none"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

None of those are on the [web search](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%23beautyblogger) results, and the second one doesn't even contain the exact search term.

Any way I can modify my request to get the same results as the web search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Search:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) to get list of match result specified in the API request. A search result set identifies matching video, channel and playlist resources.

Here's a documentation for [`Advanced search`](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2685977?hl=en), you can use advanced search operators to see list of only the videos you are searching for. For example hashtag, use `##"[tag name]"`. Use tag search for videos with a tag that you have requested.

Example:

```
##"Game Reviews" shows a list of all the videos with the tag "Game Reviews."
```

Here's a sample request including tag:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=%23%23{YOUR_TAG}&key‌​={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I found this stack overflow ticket related to your inquiry, you may try the work around offered by community: 
[How to retrieve a YouTube video's tags with YouTube v3 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240499/how-to-retrieve-a-youtube-videos-tags-with-youtube-v3-api)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I came across the docs for the advanced search. It doesn't appear to work for the API.