# Get tags for a YouTube video and search YouTube videos by tag

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I don't see any endpoint in the YouTube Data API v3 that allows:

1. Getting a list of tags associated with a video.
2. Searching `TOP N` videos that match a tag or a set of tags with some (very large) cap on N, of course. I understand why implementing this feature might pose a challenge mainly due to its data size implications. What should N be? And should we return the same N results every time for the same input? May be this can be parameterized.

Are there endpoints for these that I missed?

If not, is it a conscious decision to not have them? Do you have plans to add support for these features? If you do, when are we likely to be able to use them?

Answer (score 3):

1. Using [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) will return the associated tags for the video (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33447859/4625829)). You can test it in the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&id=RQayAl5-fTs&_h=2&). Where `id` is the Video ID (can be seen in the URL when watching a Youtube Video - `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQayAl5-fTs`).
2. For this one, unfortunately, I don't think there is an available API that does this for you automatically at the moment. However, I think what you're looking for is similar to what @typo107 is doing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36047872/4625829):

> First, retrieve a list of videos (returning minimal needed information, e.g. the video ID, title, and the high quality thumbnail URL):
>
> ```
> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={YOUR API KEY}&fields=items(id(videoId),snippet(title,thumbnails(high(url))))&part=id,snippet;
> ```
>
> Then batch the video IDs into one request to retrieve the associated tags:
>
> ```
> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key={YOUR API KEY}&fields=items(id,snippet(tags))&part=snippet&id={videoID01,videoID02,etc};
> ```

It's hard to comment on what should be the value of N (for the `Top N` videos). It's all up to you.

> *If not, is it a conscious decision to not have them? Do you have plans to add support for these features? If you do, when are we likely to be able to use them?*

I'm fairly sure that these questions are intended for *Googlers*, so I won't be commenting on them.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hadn't noticed the `tags` though I was aware of and had used the `video.list` url. Your suggestion #2 gets the tags for a specified list of videos. It appears that you're saying that there's presently no way to get/search a list of videos from out of the wild based on a tag or a set of tags?

Comment: Hi @WaterCoolerv2. For #2, just saying that there is no direct API that does this all for you. I don't think that it's impossible, but it'll be a lot of work, I guess. Cheers! :)

Comment: Is this possible today? To search youtube videos by tag?
I've gone through the documentation here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list and it's not looking like it can be done. I might be missing something.

Comment: Hey @NelsonKing I haven't touched the YouTube API for years now so I'm not up-to-date. There may have been changes since I gave this answer (3) years ago. If you're having trouble with your implementation, I would suggest posting a question. Users who are currently familiar might be able to help you out. Cheers!